# ANTLR Parser, need to which parser rule is matched

Tags: antlr

In ANTLR, for a given token, is there a way to tell which parser rule is matched?

For example, from the ANTLR grammar:

```
tokens
{
    ADD='Add';
    SUB='Sub';
}

fragment
ANYDIGIT    :   '0'..'9';

fragment
UCASECHAR   :   'A'..'Z';

fragment
LCASECHAR   :   'a'..'z';

fragment
DATEPART    :   ('0'..'1') (ANYDIGIT) '/' ('0'..'3') (ANYDIGIT) '/' (ANYDIGIT) (ANYDIGIT) (ANYDIGIT) (ANYDIGIT);

fragment
TIMEPART    :   ('0'..'2') (ANYDIGIT) ':' ('0'..'5') (ANYDIGIT) ':' ('0'..'5') (ANYDIGIT);

SPACE       :   ' ';

NEWLINE     :   '\r'? '\n';

TAB         :   '\t';

FORMFEED    :   '\f';

WS          :   (SPACE|NEWLINE|TAB|FORMFEED)+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};

IDENTIFIER  :   (LCASECHAR|UCASECHAR|'_') (LCASECHAR|UCASECHAR|ANYDIGIT|'_')*;

TIME        :   '\'' (TIMEPART) '\'';

DATE        :   '\'' (DATEPART) (' ' (TIMEPART))? '\'';

STRING      :   '\''! (.)* '\''!;

DOUBLE      :   (ANYDIGIT)+ '.' (ANYDIGIT)+;

INT         :   (ANYDIGIT)+;

literal     :   INT|DOUBLE|STRING|DATE|TIME;

var         :   IDENTIFIER;

param       :   literal|fcn_call|var;

fcn_name    :   ADD | 
                SUB | 
                DIVIDE | 
                MOD | 
                DTSECONDSBETWEEN | 
                DTGETCURRENTDATETIME |
                APPEND |
                STRINGTOFLOAT;

fcn_call    :   fcn_name WS? '('! WS? ( param WS? ( ','! WS? param)*)* ')'!;

expr        :   fcn_call WS? EOF;
```

And in Java:

```
  CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(tree);
  nodes.reset();
  Object obj;
  while((obj = nodes.nextElement()) != null)
  {
      if(nodes.isEOF(obj))
      {
          break;
      }
      System.out.println(obj);
  }
```

So, what I want to know, at `System.out.println(obj)`, did the node match the `fcn_name` rule, or did it match the `var` rule.

The reason being, I am trying to handle vars differently than `fcn_names`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot get the name of a parser rule (at least, not without an ugly hack <sup>➊</sup>).

But if `tree` is an instance of `CommonTree`, it means you've already invoked the `expr` rule of your parser, which means you already know `expr` matches first (which in its turn matches `fcn_name`).

<sup>➊</sup> On a related note, see: [Get active Antlr rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246154/get-active-antlr-rule)

Comment: Just pass the parser ruleNames into your listener.  There's a function for all the names. 
 Hardly a hack.

Comment: In Python antlr4 this would be `ast_node.parser.ruleNames[ast_node.getRuleIndex()]`.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your listener/visitor:

```
String[] ruleNames;
public void loadParser(gramParser parser) {  //get parser
    ruleNames = parser.getRuleNames(); //load parser rules from parser
}
```

Call loadParser() from wherever you create your listener/visitor, eg.:

```
MyParser parser = new MyParser(tokens);
MyListener listener = new MyListener(); 
listener.loadParser(parser);  //so we can access rule names
```

Then inside each rule you can get the name of the rule like this:

```
ruleName = ruleNames[ctx.getRuleIndex()];
```