# How to merge two ASTs?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree, lexer

I'm trying to implement a tool for merging different versions of some source code. Given two versions of the same source code, the idea would be to parse them, generate the respective Abstract Source Trees (AST), and finally merge them into a single output source keeping grammatical consistency - the lexer and parser are those of question [ANTLR: How to skip multiline comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898052/antlr-how-to-skip-multiline-comments).

I know there is class `ParserRuleReturnScope` that helps... but `getStop()` and `getStart()` always return null :-(

Here is a snippet that illustrates how I modified my perser to get rules printed:

```
parser grammar CodeTableParser;

options {
    tokenVocab = CodeTableLexer;
    backtrack = true;
    output = AST;
}

@header {
    package ch.bsource.ice.parsers;
}

@members {
    private void log(ParserRuleReturnScope rule) {
        System.out.println("Rule: " + rule.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("    getStart(): " + rule.getStart());
        System.out.println("    getStop(): " + rule.getStop());
        System.out.println("    getTree(): " + rule.getTree());
    }
}

parse
    : codeTabHeader codeTable endCodeTable eof { log(retval); }
    ;

codeTabHeader
    : comment CodeTabHeader^ { log(retval); }
    ;

...
```

Comment: I think you need additional information to be able to merge. Like a common ancestor version or at least what has been been removed, added or modified.

Comment: Maybe later... but for now the tool shall just: 1) keep common parts as they are; 2) take modifications from the newest source version; 3) keep non-common parts of both source versions. That's it.

Comment: See the update to my post for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `log(retval)` in your parser code looks like it's going to happen at the end of the rule, but it's not. You'll want to move the call into an `@after` block.

I changed `log` to spit out a message as well as the scope information and added calls to it to my own grammar like so:

```
script    
    @init {log("@init", retval);}
    @after {log("@after", retval);}
    : statement* EOF  {log("after last rule reference", retval);} 
        -> ^(STMTS statement*) 
    ;
```

Parsing test input produced the following output:

```
Logging from @init
    getStart(): [@0,0:4='Print',<10>,1:0]
    getStop(): null
    getTree(): null
Logging from after last rule reference
    getStart(): [@0,0:4='Print',<10>,1:0]
    getStop(): null
    getTree(): null
Logging from @after
    getStart(): [@0,0:4='Print',<10>,1:0]
    getStop(): [@4,15:15='<EOF>',<-1>,1:15]
    getTree(): STMTS
```

The call in the `after` block has both the `stop` and `tree` fields populated.

I can't say whether this will help you with your merging tool, but I think this will at least get you past the problem with the half-populated scope object.

Comment: Thank you :-) Now the `ParserRuleReturnScope` fields are populted. About merging the source code... well I'm just investigating how I could implement it... Anyway thank you again for your amazing support!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you *have* the ASTs (often difficult to get in the first place, parsing real languages is often harder than it looks), you first have to determine what they have in common, and build a mapping collecting that information.   That's not as easy as it looks;  do you count a block of code that has moved, but is the same exact subtree, as "common"?  What about two subtrees that are the same except for consistent renaming of an identifier?  What about changed comments? (most ASTs lose the comments; most programmers will think this is a really bad idea).

You can build a variation of the "Longest Common Substring" algorithm to compare trees.   I've used that in tools that I have built.

Finally, after you've merged the trees, now you need to regenerate the text, ideally preserving most of the layout of the original code. (Programmers hate when you change the layout they so loving produced).  So your ASTs need to capture position information, and your regeneration has to honor that where it can.

Comment: Yes... this is more or less what I did... anyway thank you very much for your interesting and useful comments :-)

Comment: I'm interested in how you actually solved the issue of merging the trees - I'm getting some troubles. How did you implement the LCS to compare trees? After you got the commont part, how did you apply the deltas to it?

Comment: We use suffix trees.  You can read about how they are used to find cloned (e.g., "common") code in http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/4023959/4023960/04023995.pdf  That gets constant subtrees that match.  You need to build some kind of unifier over what's left, and that's rather hueristic.